# A number '$Z$' contains all the digits from $1$ to $9$ exactly once. $Z$ is divisible by $99$. What will be the number on its hundreds place?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> A number '$Z$' contains all the digits from $1$ to $9$ exactly once. $Z$ is divisible by $99$. What will be the number on its hundreds place (i.e. its third-to-last digit)?

$99=9\cdot11$ so the addition of numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ is $45$ which is divisible by $9$.

To be divisible by $11$, the sum of the odd places of a number subtracted by the even places of a number must be a multiple of $11$.

How do I proceed?

Comment: how can this be possible?  The total sum is $45$ as you point out...but that is an odd number, hence can not be split into two equal sums.

Comment: @lulu The sums don't have to be equal. They may differ by 11, for example ...

Comment: As another remark, note that if it were possible  then you could interchange the hundreds place with any other even place without changing divisibility.

Comment: DIVISIBILITY CONDITION FOR 9

Comment: @jerry  Please do not use all caps.  It is annoying...looks like you are shouting.

Comment: OK ..........@lulu

Comment: @CatalinZara  Good point, thanks.  Did I also blunder in my second comment?

Comment: @CaitlinZara To illustrate your point, $6+4+5+2=17$ and $1+3+7+8+9=28$.  Thus $163475829$ is divisbile by $99$, indeed the quotient is $1651271$.  But we can swap the $8$ and the $9$, say, to get $163475928$ to get another possible solution, this time the quotient is $1651272$.

Comment: This question is busted.

Comment: @lulu Your second comment is correct and leads to the conclusion that any digit can appear on any position.

Comment: IF BUSTED,,,,NO ANSWER THEN @TonyK

Comment: @CatalinZara  that might be too strong.  My most recent comment shows that I can get $\{6,4,5,2\}$ in the hundreds place.  Not sure about the rest (but of course you may well be right...I just stopped looking after I got one partition that worked).

Comment: @jerry Can you stop using all caps? Is your caps lock key broken or something?

Comment: Another viable partition has $\{7,3,6,1\}$ in the even slots...

Comment: @lulu Any digit can appear on a sum of four or five digits equal to 17 or 28.

Comment: And another has $\{9,1,5,2\}$ and yet another has $\{8,2,4,3\}$ so now I agree...we can get any digit in any slot.

Comment: @CatalinZara  Indeed you are correct.  Just took me longer to persuade myself.

Comment: Also, there is no explicit restriction on the number and place(s) of $0$ digits.

Answer (score 1):

You must found the digits those sum's difference is a multiple of $11$ and place them on odd and even places.

One of the set of  solution is $6+4+5+2=17$ and $9+8+7+3+1=28$ since $28-17=11$ Thus $968472351$ is divisible by $99$. But we can swap the odd positioned digits with odd positioned digits and even positioned digits with even positioned digits. So the problem can have more than $(5!\times 4!=2880)$ solutions and I can't provide all the possible solutions one by one.

Comment: How can you say that it have more than $2880$ solution. Can you suggest at least $1$ different from the above mentioned.

Comment: @JustinBieber Why not just interchange $6+5+3+2+1=17$ and $9+8+7+4=28$ those are also $2880$ again

Comment: OK, Thats good.Nice answer +1